# UIView: which method is called just before being shown?

Tags: ios, layout, uiview

I would like to make some operation inside a custom `UIView`, based on its width.

Which UIView method is called just after the `UIView` dimensions have been defined and before the `UIView` is ready to be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is layoutSubviews: of the UIView class

Comment: Keep in mind that this can also be called after the view is shown.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks, I realized, so inside `LayoutSubviews` I am now testing for the condition that the width has changed. I am running my function only in that case.